# Emailing PDF generated with CakePDF

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2, CakeEmail and the CakePDF plugin

I'm trying to generate a PDF based on a view and attach it to an email. I've read the read me file but am still none the wiser. Do I have to actually create the file on the server?

This is my code so far (email gets sent but no PDF).

```
// Build PDF as attachment
        $CakePdf = new CakePdf();
        $CakePdf->template('email_view', 'default');
        //get the pdf string returned
        $pdf = $CakePdf->output();

        // SMTP Options
        $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(

            // Only to be used internally
            'port'=>'25',
            'timeout'=>'30',
            'host' => '111.111.111.111',
            'username'=>'',
            'password'=>''
         );
        $this->Email->template = 'newExpenseClaim';
        $this->Email->from    = 'Expense Tracker <james@test.com>';
        $this->Email->to      = 'james@test.com'; 
        $this->Email->subject = 'New Expense Claim Submitted - Please Review';
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'both';
        $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';

        $this->Email->attachments = $pdf;

        // Set username & url in email
        $this->set('user', $fu['User']['name']);
        $this->set('ms', $ms);
        $this->Email->send();
        $this->set('smtp_errors', $this->Email->smtpError);
```

Here is the read me from github:

https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: OK, looks like you cant do it this way - you have to create the file on the server and then attach. However, I now have an issue setting view vars as the view template path you have to set is outside of my controller/view folder. Basically if I could change: $CakePdf->template('email_view', 'default'); to something like: $CakePdf->template('MyControllerName/email_view', 'default'); it would work - the plugin owner said use $CakePdf->viewVars() but didnt provide details of how to pass info ($CakePdf->viewVars('expenseClaim', $this->ExpenseClaim->read(null, $id));) doesnt work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this to work, heres what I did:

```
// Build PDF
$CakePdf = new CakePdf();

// Add disbursements onto array
$merged = array_merge($expenseClaim, $expenseTotal, $approvedBy, $disbursements);

$CakePdf->viewVars($merged);
$CakePdf->template('email_view', 'default');
$filename = 'expense-claim-' .$id. '.pdf';
$CakePdf->write(APP . 'files' . DS . $filename);
```

Basically, I merged all the data I needed to pass to the PDF view into one array then passed it using viewVars().

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I found the above needed a slight modification: $CakePdf->viewVars(compact('user', 'adverts', 'incomes', 'customs', 'category_name', 'deductions', 'formvalues')); (Note the compact within viewVars around the arrays)

Comment: Hello James, I have seen your post in `git` also for same issue. I could not solve my issue i.e. same as you. I want to generate PDF from controller and send in email, but my engine is `wkhtmltopdf` and that is not working. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I am using TCPDF.
This is how I do it. Adapt it to your code:

```
$pdf->Content($cvData);
$content = $pdf->Output($cvFileName, 'S');
file_put_contents(TMP . $cvFileName, $content);
$this->Email->attachments = array($cvFileName=>TMP . $cvFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do I pass it view vars? with it being outsite of MyControllerName/View

Comment: Tried your suggestion and got this:

Fatal Error
Error: Call to a member function Content() on a non-object 
File: C:\wamp\www\expenseApp\app\Controller\ExpenseClaimsController.php 
Line: 416